# Laravel 8 none existing route after deleting work

Tags: laravel-8

i had `checkAuth` route in `routes` early and now it doesn't defined in routes because i deleted that

you can see this output:

```
php artisan route:list
```

output:

> Your application doesn't have any routes matching the given criteria.

now when i try to test this route, it worked :|

```
192.168.1.103:8000/checkAuth

True, you are logged!!
```

this commands with restarting server and change host with port couldn't resolve this issue:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 0):

we had the same problem in our project. If you had the websockets package, the problem is in the `WebSocketsServiceProvider.php` file.

In my package on line 49, I have the line `$this->registerDashboard();` which registers routing and gateway for the dashboard from WebSockets. You can return an empty string in `registerDashboardRoutes` if you don't need the dashboard.

Comment: when we had this problem we downgraded project and our problem solved, I'm not sure the `websockets` caused this problem. because we didn't use that. i think `xampp` caused this problem